# extract payload from tcpflow output

Tags: shell, http-headers, packet-capture

Tcpflow outputs a bunch of files, many of which are HTTP responses from a web server. Inside, they contain HTTP headers, including Content-type: , and other important ones.  I'm trying to write a script that can extract just the payload data (i.e. image/jpeg; text/html; et al.) and save it to a file [optional: with an appropriate name and file extension].

The EOL chars are \r\n (CRLF) and so this makes it difficult to use in GNU distros (in my experiences).

I've been trying something along the lines of:

```
sed /HTTP/,/^$/d
```

To delete all text from the the beginning of HTTP (incl) to the end of \r\n\r\n (incl) but I have found no luck. I'm looking for help from anyone with good experience in `sed` and/or `awk`. I have zero experience with Perl, please I'd prefer to use common GNU command line utilities for this

<strike>Find a sample tcpflow output file here.</strike> (bad link)

Thanks,
Felipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/558) recommends running [`foremost`](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) on output from `tcpflow` to extract the images. It's available at that link and in the repositories of (at least) Debian, Fedora and Ubuntu.

I tried it on the sample file you linked to and it seemed to work fine.

```
foremost -i tcpflow.out
```

It created a directory called "output" with subdirectories called "gif" and "jpeg" with files in each. The names of the files don't match the filenames in the headers, though.

To change the line endings of your files do:

```
dos2unix filename
```

or in a pipe:

```
dos2unix < filename | nextcommand
```

Other links of interest:

- [httpflow](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2005/03/16/httpflow-tcpflow-parser-to-help-debug-http/) - parses tcpflow output
- [tcpxtract](http://tcpxtract.sourceforge.net/) - another file extractor
- [Forensic Tools for Unix](http://www.opensourceforensics.org/tools/unix.html) - a list of open source tools